# Load image from URL in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have this construction:

```pascal
image.bitmap.Assign(nil);

TTask.Run(procedure
begin
  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
  begin
    label_loader.visible:=true;
  end);

  ReadImageFromWeb(image,url);     //load image from URL

  TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure
  begin
    label_loader.visible:= false;
  end);
end);
```

```pascal
procedure ReadImageFromWeb(image:TImage;url: string);
var
  memStream   : TMemoryStream;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  memStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

  try
    IdHTTP.Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    IdHTTP.Request.Connection  := 'keep-alive';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    IdHTTP.Request.Charset     := 'utf-8';
    IdHTTP.Request.Pragma := 'no-cache';

    IdHTTP.Get(url,memStream);
  except
    ShowMessage('Image not found');
    memStream.Free;
    IdHTTP.Free;
    exit;
  end;
  try
    memStream.Position:=0;
    image.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(memStream);
  finally
    memStream.Free;
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Every now and again, despite the fact that the picture has been downloaded, it is not displayed in the `TImage` object.
This only happens if procedure `ReadImageFromWeb()` is under construction with `TTask`. If I delete `TTask`, there is no such problem.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems that you're aware of not touching UI from outside of main thread, because you use `TThread.Synchronize`. Yet you assign `TImage`'s bitmap in worker thread in procedure `ReadImageFromWeb`. In case of an error in you show a message to the user, which is [not the right thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26718030/delphi-application-hangs-while-showmessage-or-messagedlg). Even though Embarcadero [entices you to do so](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Using_TTask_from_the_Parallel_Programming_Library).

Comment: I'm also concerned about your "funky" exception handling inside `ReadImageFromWeb`.

Comment: @PeterWolf `ShowMessage` also needs to be synchronized, too

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's what I pointed out, didn't I?

Comment: @Olaf what is "under construction with `TTask`" supposed to mean exactly? In any case, `TTask` (and the PPL in general) has been plagued with problems since the day it was introduced. After many years, Embarcadero still can't seem to make it work correctly. I stay away from it at all costs and just use `TThread` instead. If you want reliable pooling and such, consider using a 3rd party library instead, like [OmniThreadLibrary](http://www.omnithreadlibrary.com).

Comment: @remy I meant the procedure readimagefromWeb is in the "middle" of ttask procedure/construction

Comment: @Olaf I don't understand what you are trying to describe. The procedure is a standalone entity, it is fully formed before the `TTask` ever sees it. The only construction is the `TTask` itself, and it is fully created before it is run.

Comment: Yes, that's right.  the procedure is a separate unit.  If procedure works without TTask everything is OK.  If works with TTask sometimes the pictures are not displayed in Timage.

Comment: ``image.Bitmap.LoadFromStream`` should be wrapped inside of a ``TThread.Syncronize``, too!